# How do I determine if a database role exists in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out how I can check if a database role exists in SQL Server.  I want to do something like this:

```
if not exists (select 1 from sometable where rolename='role')
begin
CREATE ROLE role
    AUTHORIZATION MyUser;
end
```

What table/proc should I use here?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
SELECT DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID('role')
--or
IF DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID('role') IS NULL
```

[USER_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181466.aspx) is deprecated and could break. [CREATE ROLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187936%28SQL.90%29.aspx) indicates SQL 2005+ so it's OK

Comment: @Klaus: try and create a role + user with the same name. It will fail. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx "name" colun is unique

Answer (score 31):

```
if not exists (select 1 from sys.database_principals where name='role' and Type = 'R')
begin
CREATE ROLE role
    AUTHORIZATION MyUser;
end
```

Comment: This fails if you have a user who happens to have the same "role" name. Odd, but you'd have to remove the "= 'R'" to work 100%

Comment: @Klaus what have I got to do with this?

Comment: Shouldn't there be `(select top 1 from...` at the beginning of condition?

Comment: @Gucu112, top 1 is not necessary, and in fact would likely slow down the query (albeit very little).

Comment: Sorry, my bad. In fact I have double-checked and it depends of what you would like to achieve. In case mentioned by the author selecting just 1 as value is sufficient.