# Check if role exists in DB?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, permissions, roles

I want to add users to the same role in more than one database. However the role may or may not be present in each database. How can I check if the role exists in each database and if it does, add users to that role?

e.g.
IF role exists
BEGIN
    Add user in role
END

Comment: Please refer to this link. Probably the same thing you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201160/how-do-i-determine-if-a-database-role-exists-in-sql-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I determine if a database role exists in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201160/how-do-i-determine-if-a-database-role-exists-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try:

```
IF DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID('role') IS NULL
BEGIN
  -- add user here
  CREATE ROLE role AUTHORIZATION MyUser;
END
```

Comment: This fails if you have a user who happens to have the same "role" name

Comment: Note too that meta-data functions (like DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID()) will frequently, by design, use low-level blocking....

Answer (score 8):

```
IF EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1
    FROM sys.database_principals
    WHERE type_desc = 'DATABASE_ROLE'
    AND name = 'name'
)
BEGIN
  -- add user;
END
```

Answer (score 5):

I can't comment yet, so I have to add this as an answer.

I like to be as specific as possible, which is why I prefer including the principal type. This is why I up voted Aaron's answer.

Using DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID could give unexpected results if there is another principal type with the same name as the role that you want to add. This is because DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID returns the ID number of a **principal** in the current database, not specifically for a principal with a type of database role.

Let's say that you have a user with the same name as the database role. The status of Yada's script would indicate success, but it would not add the role because there is already a **principal** with that name. However, Aaron's script would return the following error:

> User, group, or role 'name' already exists in the current database.

I'd rather catch this issue early on (e.g. when the script is run) than later on (e.g. when my app is being used).

Here's what I'd normally use:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM sys.database_principals WHERE [name] = 'role_name' AND [type]='R')
BEGIN
    -- add user;
END
```

If I really want to handle this scenario and not show an error, I could use something like this:

```
DECLARE @RoleName sysname,
        @PrincipalType NVARCHAR(60);

SET @RoleName = 'role_name';
SET @PrincipalType = (SELECT type_desc FROM sys.database_principals WHERE [name] = @RoleName);

IF @PrincipalType IS NULL
BEGIN
    -- Add user;
END
ELSE IF @PrincipalType <> 'DATABASE_ROLE'
BEGIN
    --Deal with the issue as desired. Here we're printing out a warning. Important: The status will still indicate that the Query executed successfully when using PRINT to show warnings.
    PRINT 'WARNING: The ' + @RoleName + ' database role was not created. A principal already exists in the database with a type of ' + @PrincipalType + '.';
END
```