# Check if a role exists in PostgreSQL using psql

Tags: bash, psql

I need in a bash script a `IF` condition on the existence of a role in a PostgreSQL database. I have found solutions in SQL code [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184889/check-if-role-exists-in-db), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092086/create-postgresql-role-user-if-it-doesnt-exist)], but I need something I can use directly in bash, I assume with the help of `psql`. In [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092086/create-postgresql-role-user-if-it-doesnt-exist)] there are also `psql` solutions, but I don't manage to adapt it in a `IF` statement.

I have tried this unsuccessfully (I am a PostgreSQL and bash newbie):

```
psql_USER=my
if [ "$( psql -h db -U postgres --no-psqlrc --single-transaction --pset=pager=off --tuples-only --set=ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -tc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_user WHERE usename = $psql_USER" | grep -q 1 )" == '1'  ]  > /dev/null 2> /dev/null; then
    echo "HOURRA !"
fi;
```

Result is:

```
Password for user postgres: 
ERROR:  column « my » does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT 1 FROM pg_user WHERE usename = my
                                              ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid the quoting problem like this:

```bash
if psql -Atq -c "SELECT '@' || usename || '@' FROM pg_user" | grep -q '@'"$psql_USER"'@'
then
    echo yes
fi
```

The `psql` invocation selects a list of all usernames, prefixed and suffixed with `@`. The `grep` has return code 0 if `psql_USER` contains one of these user names, else 1. The `then` branch of `if` is only taken if the return code of the pipeline is 0, that is, if the user exists in the database.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain a little please?