# Roles in SQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I’m trying to create a role then I receive the error *“role exists”* and I have to deleted first and repeat the process.

- How may I check if a role exists in my sql database in sql server 2008 r2?
- Is there any `sys.table` to search for it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I determine if a database role exists in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201160/how-do-i-determine-if-a-database-role-exists-in-sql-server)

Comment: Yes but in this table `database_principals` are only the roles which the system create... what about the roles I have create? where I'll found them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [sys.database_principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx) view:

```
select * from sys.database_principals where name = @Role_Name and type = 'R'
```

it's also possible to use [database_principal_id](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187319.aspx):

```
select database_principal_id(@Role_Name)
```

Comment: Yes but in this table `sys.database_principals` are only the roles which the system create... what about the roles which I have create? where I'll found them?

Comment: you'll find them in sys.database_principals - try it.

Comment: Yes you have right... the reason that i didn't find it there was that I didn't add  a `schema` to the role... thats why I'm not seen it in view `sys.database_principals`